# Register class function as global

Tags: php, nusoap

I'd like to register a class method under NuSOAP, but instead of registering it as its member, I'd rather it was in the global scope. Here's some code to picture what I mean (obviously not working):

```
class SOAPInterface
{
        public function Authenticate($walkid,$asdf)
        {
                return 7;
        }
}

        $namespace = '';
        $server = new soap_server();
        $server->debug_flag = false;
        $server->configureWSDL("WackyWsdl", $namespace,"my_wsdl_url");
        $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;

        $server->register('SOAPInterface.Authenticate',                    // method name
          array('ContractorId' => 'xsd:int', 'Password'=>'xsd:string'),          // input parameters
          array('return' => 'xsd:int'),    // output parameters
          $namespace,                         // namespace
         $namespace . '#Authenticate',                   // soapaction
          'rpc',                                    // style
          'encoded',                                // use
          'Some doc'        // documentation
        );

        $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'])
                  ? $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] : '';
        $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
        $this->autoRender = false;
        exit();
```

In this example I'd like `Authenticate` to be called as `Authenticate`, not `SOAPInterface.Authenticate`.Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: I believe what you are talking about is static methods. These are not global per say, but might do what you are expecting.

Comment: Well, they'd do. The point is to change their scope in WSDL (and make it work).

Comment: @datasage `global` is exactly what `static` class methods are. Whether or not one should go down that path is up to the individual. It's rife with all the pitfalls and problems associated with `global`, though, so be careful ...

Comment: I don't think a SOAP method can be static since it's always going to be related to a particular object, but even if you could, a static method is referred to by `Classname::methodname()`, so you'd still have to specify the full name. In any case, globals are generally considered a sign of poor coding style: if global seems to be the answer, there's almost always a better way of doing it.

Comment: I need to implement an interface with names given in a public context. The question is whether `methodname()` could automatically translate to `Classname::methodname()` on NuSOAP side.